# What does the "Hexagonal" in Hexagonal Architecture mean?

Tags: design-patterns

I was reading through the Hexagonal Architecture and somehow I understood the concept but I am keen to understand why it is called **`Hexagonal.`**

Comment: thanks @ojonugwa ochalifu for making it correct

Comment: What do you mean by "I understood the concept"? Do you know what a "port" is? Do you know what an "adapter" is?

Comment: yes @choquero70  its very similar to adapt like.. we have moble or laptop adaptor in layman terms. if not please correct me

Comment: I never do that comparison. But I tihink some people does.

Answer (score 4):

The Hexagonal Architecture got its name from the way Alistair Cockburn diagrams the pattern. It has nothing to do with the actual code.

> The hexagon is not a hexagon because the number six is important, but rather to allow the people doing the drawing to have room to insert ports and adapters as they need, not being constrained by a one-dimensional layered drawing. The term "Hexagonal Architecture" comes from this visual effect.

Source: https://declara.com/content/va7eLmgJ